# .NET Chart and show all axis X labels

Tags: c#, .net, charts, axis

I have a chart control that I use to show sound pressure lines.

So the X axis is

```
31.5 63 125 250 500 1000 2000 4000 and 8000.
```

I set the chart logarithmic on and the log base to 10.

But I'm not able to show all these labels on the axis, it shows `31.5 315` and 3150 only.

Tried to put interval to 1 but no luck.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: To get full control over the labelling you may need to use CustomLabels

Comment: I tried that but then the chart don't show labels at all

Comment: True, its either Labels or CustomLabels.

Comment: So I add my labels then how can I disable the standard ones and use my customs?

Comment: Please, see my following answer

Comment: 1) You should post answers only if they actually have solved your problem; if they are a variant of the question, please post the code in the question! 2) How are the dataoints added? what are the x-values? If the labels don't show, maybe the datapoints don't let them?

Comment: Sorry, I deleted the wrong answer.
Anyway I found the solution. Because of the axis is logarithmic, the From and To positions must be Log of position values.

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

To make `CustomLabels` show up on your axis you need to create them with at least these three properties:

- `Text`
- `FromPosition`
- `ToPosition`

Here is an example:

[image]

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Series S2 = chart1.Series.Add("Series2");
    ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
    CA.AxisY.IsLogarithmic = true;

    List<double> fr = new List<double>();
    for (int i = 3; i < 18; i++ )
    {
        fr.Add(Math.Pow(2, 1f * i / 2));
    }

        for (int i = 1; i < fr.Count; i+=2)
        {
            CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
            cl.FromPosition =  fr[i - 1];
            cl.ToPosition = fr[i + 1];
            cl.Text = fr[i] + " Hz";
            CA.AxisY.CustomLabels.Add(cl);

        }

    for (int i = 1; i < 60; i++)
    {
        chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(i, Math.Pow(2, i));
        chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(i, i * i);
    }

}
```

Note that for best precision you should use `FromPositions` and `ToPositions` that don't fall on the `Labels` but right between. So I skip every other step in the list of frequency steps for the displayed `Labels` and use them instead for their `FromPositions` and `ToPositions`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your example. Maybe I used wrong from and to positions when I loaded custom labels.

Comment: Please have a look at the changed code; I have created a list of steps in math and use only every other for the labels and the other ones for the to- and frompositions